# same image under f, but not under f'

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Let $f$ be a non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.
We claim the existence of some real number $a$ such that the implication
$$f(x)=f(x+a) \implies f'(x)\neq f'(x+a) \qquad (\star)$$
holds for all real numbers $x$.

Proof:
If $f(b)=f(a+b)$ and $f'(b)=f'(b+a)$ with $a\neq 0$, then $f'$ has two roots in the interval $[b,b+a]$. So assume
that $b_0<\ldots<b_m$ are the roots of $f'$ and let $\varepsilon$ be the minimum of $b_{i+1}-b_{i}$. Now choose $a$ arbitrary in the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$.

I have the following questions:

- Is the same true if $f$ is a non-constant rational function in $\mathbb{R}(X)$?
- What happens if we consider $\mathbb{C}$? Is it true that for every non-constant rational function $f$ in $\mathbb{C}(X)$ there is a complex number $a$ such that $(\star)$ holds?

Comment: If $\deg f=n, a \ne 0$ then $f(x+a)-f(x)$ has degree $n-1$ and $f'(x)-f'(x+a)$ has degree $n-2$ so in particular if $n \ge 3$ is odd, $f'(x)-f'(x+a)$ will have a real root for any real $a \ne 0$ so not sure exactly what is the question

Comment: @Conrad, the premise of the question seems to be that $f(x+a) = f(x)$ for all $x$, which means that $f$ is constant.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @avs that premise would denote a lack of mathematical knowledge beyond 5th grade and the question should be closed if so - my understanding of the problem is that one can find an $a$ for which $f(x+a)-f(x)$ has real roots but not $f'(x+a)-f'(x)$ and that is also incorrect in general as noted

Comment: @avs: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your example. In your example the implication $(\star)$ holds for every non-zero real number $a$, because here $f(x)=f(x+a)$ is only true if $a=-2x$ and $f'(x)\neq f'(x+(-2x))$.

Comment: @Conrad@avs: I am looking for some $a$ such that the implication $(\star)$ is true for all $x$. That means, I am looking for some $a$ such that $f'(x)\neq f'(x+a)$ whenever $f(x)=f(x+a)$.

Comment: now it makes more sense - if I get it right, you want to prove that there is a real $a$ st $f(x+a)-f(x)$  has no double (real) roots

Comment: Thank you Conrad. You are right, this is precisely the question.